Mûr pour la froide pierre
What does this "plaisanterie" mean? From Le Désert de l'amour (François Mauriac), where two characters are discussing the 50-year-old doctor's obsession with the 27-year-old Maria Cross:

« Tu ne sais pas ce que j'imagine ? Tu ne te moqueras pas ? Le docteur aurait été un peu amoureux de moi, à Bordeaux... cela ne m'étonnerait pas du tout. »
Victor Larousselle répondit, d'une bouche pâteuse, qu'il n'était pas jaloux ; et une de ses plus vieilles plaisanteries lui revint : « Encore un qui est mûr pour la froide pierre. »

I believe the syntax is as straightforward as it seems: "Yet another one (fellow) who's ready for the cold stone." But what could that be playing on?

Une citation plus complète eût été nécessaire : Il ajouta que le pauvre homme avait eu sans doute une petite attaque, beaucoup de ses clients, qui n'osaient pas le lâcher, consultaient en secret d'autres médecins.  La froide pierre c'est le tombeau, la mort donc.

About your question: "But what could that be playing on?". Plaisanterie doesn't imply a play on words, it's just Paroles, plus ou moins spirituelles, plus ou moins drôles (TLF) Propos destinés à faire rire, à amuser. (Robert). Plaisanterie is not "a pun".

Tombeau, c'est la première idée qui m'était venu à l'esprit.

La citation complète éclaire le sens de cette expression  :

Victor Larousselle répondit, d'une bouche pâteuse, qu'il n'était pas jaloux ; et une de ses plus vieilles plaisanteries lui revint : « Encore un qui est mûr pour la froide pierre. » Il ajouta que le pauvre homme avait eu sans doute une petite attaque, beaucoup de ses clients, qui n'osaient pas le lâcher, consultaient en secret d'autres médecins.

Les clients du médecin le lâchaient parce qu'ils pensaient, qu'ayant eu une attaque, il était prêt (mûr) pour aller dans la tombe, c'est à dire qu'il risquait de mourir.
La froide pierre c'est la froide pierre du tombeau. On trouve l'expression surtout dans des écrits religieux. Par exemple :

Nous briserons aussi
Un jour la froide pierre,
Un jour nous atteindrons
Le seuil d’éternité ;
Et là nous recevrons,
Dans la maison du Père,
Un bonheur éternel :
Christ est ressuscité !  1


Comme lui, du tombeau
brisant la froide pierre,
Nous nous réveillerons pour l'immortalité,   2

François Mauriac était catholique et connaissait certainement bien les textes religieux mais l'expression est employée au delà de textes religieux.

Oui, si ce livre pouvait pénétrer sous la froide pierre qui couvre les Tracy, les Say, les Comte, je crois que les ossements de ces illustres philanthropes tressailleraient de joie dans la tombe.   3


De la vie, on croyait que sous la froide pierre
S’ouvrait un gouffre de lumière ;
La mort était alors un bien.  4

L'expression est aussi connue au Québec, on la trouve dans La croix de ma mère, qui fait partie du Chansonnier canadien pour l'école et le foyer de Uldéric Allaire 5.

1 Un chant protestant, dans lequel l'expression est, me semble-t-il, très claire, briser la froide pierre, c'est briser la pierre tombale, ressusciter. 
2  Chant du théologien Alfred Kuen.
3Dans cette phrase l'économiste Frédéric Bastiat fait référence à des penseurs du passé, et déjà morts envers lesquels il a une dette intellectuelle.  
4Mors, poème sur la mort de Camille Saint-Saëns, in Rimes familières.
5 P.106.

Ah, nice! So it's not a comment on Maria's speculation at all, not a remark on misplaced love, just a reference to his age. Merci.
